# Return the index of largest sum within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to JavaScript.  I'm working on a bit of a coding problem, and I'm running into a wall.  Here's the code I'm having trouble with so far:

```
function creditCardTest (creditCardNumbers) {
var creditCardNumbers = [
                                            '7629-1648-1623-7952', 
                                            '4962-1694-2293-7910', 
                                            '9999-9999-9999-9999', /*For test purposes*/
                                            '4921-2090-4961-7308'
                                            ]
var sumArray = [ ]; //parallel to creditCardNumbers array
var largestValue = 0;
var locationOfLargest = 0;
var itemSum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < creditCardNumbers.length; i++) {

    var creditCardItem = creditCardNumbers [ i ];
    /*console.log(creditCardItem); For test purposes*/
    itemSum = 0; //required for functionality

    for (var j = 0; j < creditCardItem.length; j++) {

        var stringChar = creditCardItem.charAt( j );
        /*console.log(stringChar); For test purposes*/

            if ( stringChar >= '0' && stringChar <= '9' ) {
                itemSum += parseInt(stringChar);
                /*console.log(parseInt(stringChar)); For test purposes*/
            }

    }

    sumArray[ i ] = itemSum;
    console.log(sumArray[ i ]); /*required for functionality*/

}

if (!largestValue || sumArray[ i ] > largestValue) {
largestValue = sumArray[ i ];
locationOfLargest = i;
}

console.log(locationOfLargest);
```

}

creditCardTest( );

I'm looking to return the largest index in an array, but I'm only getting the 0th index as a result.  Any input?

Comment: where is the for?

Comment: In the title you have written *index of largest sum* and later on you are writing that you looking for *largest index*. So what exactly you are looking for then?

Comment: I apologize, just edited to show my full code.

Comment: mm, as i  see you need to sum accounts numbers?

Comment: Your if test have to be in the scope of your first loop for. You check for i index but it is undefined.

Comment: yes, that is the case here.  sum them up, and find the value with the largest sum and return it in its original form at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6hd85ts/)

```js
var largestValue = 0,
    locationOfLargest = 0,
    sumArray = [1, 100, 909, 8, 91098, 923823];
    for (var i = 0; i < sumArray.length; i++) {
      if (!largestValue || sumArray[i] > largestValue) {
        largestValue = sumArray[i];
        locationOfLargest = i;
      }
    }

console.log(locationOfLargest, largestValue);
```

or even a quicker solution:

```js
var arr = [1, 100, 909, 8, 91098, 923823],
        index = arr.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, arr));
        console.log(index);
```

Comment: While your chunk of code does work, I already have an array defined.  I just edited my question to show the full code, maybe there might be something I'm missing?

Comment: only add your array, to your questio, it will be more of 1000 items?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a step by step approach

- get first an array of digits
- add the digits
- get the index of max sum.

```js
var data = ['7629-1648-1623-7952', '4962-1694-2293-7910', '9999-9999-9999-9999', '4921-2090-4961-7308'],
    index = data.
        map(a => a.match(/\d/g)).
        map(a => a.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b)).
        reduce((r, a, i, aa) => !i || aa[r] < a ? i : r, -1);

console.log(index);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```